# Como faço para retirar um item de um array ou colocar a cada click?

Tags: javascript, html

Vamos supor que tenho o array "id"

> `id = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,..., 25]`

Daí eu tenho os botões em HTML

> `<button id="1">1</button>...`

Eu gostaria que quando eu apertasse um botão no HTML, aparecesse seu valor na array, mas se eu apertar ele novamente o seu valor desaparecesse. Como que eu faço?

(Sou ainda novato em JS, to com mta dúvida)

Answer (score -2):

No exemplo, eu adiciono um listener pra cada botão pra observar quando um é clicado.

Quando algum botão é clicado, a função irá ser chamada recebendo o evento, por este evento é possível acessar o valor do botão. Então, com esse valor em mãos, é verificado se o valor já existe no array, caso ainda não exista, insere, caso já exista, remove.

```js
const selected = []

const onButtonClick = (event)=>{
  const value = event.target.value
  //procura pelo valor no array
  const index = selected.findIndex((v)=> value === v)
  if(index === -1){
    //se não achar, inclui
    selected.push(value)
  }
  else{
    //se achar remove
    selected.splice(index, 1)
  }
  //printa o array
  console.log(selected)
}

//seleciona todos os botões adiciona um listener
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(button=>{
  button.addEventListener('click',onButtonClick)
})
```

```html
<button value="1">Botão 1</button>
<button value="2">Botão 2</button>
<button value="3">Botão 3</button>
```